# More Sprite Kit Game modes

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite

I have a small game and I wish to present, in the menu, 2 game modes:
I have the first up and running from my original sprite kit scene and, in order to build my second one, I added another view to the storyboard, created another scene, linked them up just like the originals:

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
skView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

and linked it to another button in my menu. The problem was, whenever i would press the button to go to the second game mode I would get a SIGABRT Thread 1 error. I made sure everything I linked was declared and valid and still got the error. I then removed the second SKScene (MyScene) and the view was loaded with no problem... just no content.

Is there a specific way I must proceed in order to have another View linked to a SpriteKit game?

Comment: Could you post more details about the SIGKILL error?

Comment: @akashg I meant to say SIGABRT Thread error, sorry, will correct it now.